# Why does $\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{S}^1 \cong \mathbb{S}^2$ hold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, projective-space

Good evening.

I recently stumbled across the claim $$\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{S}^1 \cong\mathbb{S}^2,$$
which is not really clear to me. Here, $\mathbb{R}P^3$ denotes real projective space of dimension $3$.

I know that $\mathbb{R}P^3 \cong\mathbb{S}^3/\mathbb{Z}_2$ (more or less per definition) and $\mathbb{S}^3/\mathbb{S}^1 \cong\mathbb{S}^2$ (due to Hopf), but I'm unsure how exactly to proceed.

**Edit**
The context in which $\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{S}^1$ arises is the following: The space of parametrized great circles on $\mathbb{S}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^3$ (which can be shown by identifying it first with the unit tangent bundle $S\mathbb{S}^2$, and then using $S\mathbb{S}^2 \cong SO(3) \cong \mathbb{R}P^3$) and admits a $\mathbb{S}^1$-action by time-shift, i.e. by unparametrizing the great circles.

Comment: 1. Briefly, the Hopf fibration factors through the quotient of $S^3$ by the antipodal map. (Both mappings come from complex scalar multiplication on $\mathbf{C}^{2}$.) 2. Strictly, writing quotients of spaces without context is ambiguous; we need to know the equivalence relation. (Group action? Collapsing a subspace to a point? Something else?)

Comment: I voted to close your question because the meaning of $\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{S}^1$ is unclear. It must be the orbit set of some action, but of which precisely?

Comment: Let $S^1\to S^3\to S^2$ be the Hopf fibration. Take the quotient by $\pm1$ on the fiber and the total space, giving $S^1/\pm1\simeq S^1\to S^3/\pm1\simeq\mathbb{RP}^3\to S^2$. Taking such quotients is allowed, which can be checked from the explicit description of the fibration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be a point of the unit sphere $S^{2}$ embedded in Euclidean three-space, let $S_{p}$ denote the oriented, unit-speed parametrized unit circle in the tangent plane $T_{p}S^{2}$, so that $C_{p} = S_{p} - p$ is an oriented great circle on $S^{2}$. As noted in the question, the union of these circles may be viewed as $SO(3) \simeq \mathbf{RP}^{3}$, and the circle action described in the question rotates $S_{p} \subset T_{p}S^{2}$ about $p$ compatibly with its orientation.

The total space $\mathbf{RP}^{3}$ with this group action is a principal circle bundle whose projection mapping $\mathbf{RP}^{3} \to S^{2}$ sends each $S_{p}$ to $p$. That is, the quotient space is $\mathbf{RP}^{3}/S^{1} \simeq S^{2}$.

[image: Oriented unit circles: equatorial, and in a tangent plane to the unit sphere]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Now it is clear to me. Could you please also tell me what program you used to create this beautiful visualization?

Comment: I use [ePiX](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html).